# Setting Source Location of Arrival at XYZ inside an agent

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent called 'ship2' that resides in 'main'. I would like to use a source block (in 'main') to generate a material agent at a particular XYZ coordinate in 'ship'.

I can define a node (called n_area) in 'ship2' an then put the following in the source block. This works as the material agent appears inside 'ship'. However I do not want to do it using this method as I want to control the exact location of the material agent and I don't want to set up 100s of nodes.

[image]

I tried setting the 'Location of Arrival' as (x,y,z) but I don't know the syntax to put into the X, Y, and Z fields.

In addition, ultimately I would like to generate x, y, z using a function.

Is it possible to use the source block to do the above? Or is there a better method (using an Enter block perhaps)?

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried setting the 'Location of Arrival' as (x,y,z) but I don't know the syntax to put into the X, Y, and Z fields.

You can simply use `setXY(x,y)` on the creation of the agent. (assuming you do not need z, else `setXYZ(...)`)

Or you use the x,y,z setup (using whatever xyz additions you like):
[image]

However, you always need to be a bit careful with positions. If the agents always live "within" ship, you might want to have their agent population in `Ship` and create them in a Source object within Ship.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Benjamin. However, I don't believe that is exactly what I'm after. The above would create the material agent at a location in 'main' that is relative to 'ship2', is that correct? That is, if 'ship2' then moves, the material agents will not move with it. 

Further, the material agents will move between 'ship2' and 'main' so I think generating them with a Source block in main will work better in this case.

Comment: True ,wasnt sure which one you meant. In that case, have a population within Ship and use a source within Ship to create your agents directly in ship and then, their position is relative to Ship only.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin, that should work for having the agents move with the ship. However, as mentioned I do need to transfer these agents to main at some stage. Would this hinder that process?

Perhaps I should be clearer with the big picture. The material agents are shipping containers. They need to be created on the ship and be moved with the ship to a berth. From there the containers will be lifted off the ship with a crane (in main) and then moved to other locations (within the 'main' space). As such, the agents spend most of the time in main. Apologies for not telling the whole story first.

Comment: Having "container" populations in both your "ship" and "main" agents is the correct way of transferring the containers between different upper-level agents. As for their relative position, just call the method Benjamin wrote above whenever the containers switch populations, which I believe, in your case, should be whenever the movement by crane begins.

Comment: Thanks Shingston and Benjamin. I have changed the setup and have pretty much got it working. Just stuck on one aspect. How do I transfer the container from "ship" to "main"? At the moment I am using an Exit block in ship and sending it to main by main.enter.take(agent). However the container stays in the population in Ship. I have a population in main but that stays empty after the agent goes to the enter block even though I have the 'Add Newborns To' pointing to the population in main. Is it because it's not a 'new born'? Thanks

Comment: always open new issues here on SOF, this is not a forum :) See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Noted, thanks Benjamin. Sorted the issue with gotoPopulation. Cheers